# Unidentified phone on network

Tags: security, home-networking

I have an on my network.

[image]

It does not belong to me or anyone else I know. Is this a problem? Does this just mean that my network can detect a nearby phone or should I be worried that someone has access to my network and computer? Do I need to take any steps to secure my network or computer at this time?

I could be overreacting but I know little about network security or what it means to have a device I don't recognize appear on it.

Comment: You should _always_ treat _any_ device with internet access as "exposed", and take precautions to protect it. Home wireless networks should always require WPA2 or stronger authentication before permitting a device to connect, and if you can manage the router to disallow unrecognized MAC addresses, you should.

Comment: So I definitely require WPA2 authentication to get to access my network. Does the fact that the phone appeared under network mean that the phone knew my network password?

Comment: Do you have Bluetooth enabled? (That it does not have a Mac address, and that it's appearing as a discovered device imply to me this is not someone who has had your WIFI)

Comment: Yes. I use Bluetooth headphones.

Comment: I'm not an expert, but I think this is a badly configured phone on Bluetooth. Does it go away when you disable that?

Comment: It actually disappeared on its own after about 10 minutes. Could correlate to someone leaving BT range? I know I'm probably overreacting about this but, again, I know next to nothing about network security other than setting up a WPA2.

Comment: Is this Windows 10?

Comment: Yes. This is Windows 10.

Comment: I had a similar issue.  It was an HTC device that kept popping up.  It did not appear, however, when I was in the router looking at connected devices and only appeared from the network page in Windows 10.

Comment: That's good to hear. I'll check my connected devices and make sure it's not appearing. I will also look at disallowing unrecognized MAC addresses; but does that also mean authorized visitors won't be able to connect to my network?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows 10: Phones appearing in Network](https://superuser.com/questions/976750/windows-10-phones-appearing-in-network)

Comment: Any solution to this problem?